# React canvas ctx.fillStyle is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

[image]

I have tried the function up and down writing it. Tried using different colors. Any more suggestion? Refer to the screenshot picture of my codes and output.

Comment: `.stroke` won't fill it in; use `.fill` for that

Answer (score 1):

After the fillStyle you need to append a new line with following code.

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(200, 100, 200, 200);
```